# Abbreviate @specialized

Tags: scala

I remember PaulP showed a cool trick to abbreviate repeated long `@specialized` sequences, but I don't find the original post any more. Like I have

```
trait Foo[@specialized(Int, Float, Double, Long, Char, Boolean) A]
trait Bar[@specialized(Int, Float, Double, Long, Char, Boolean) A]
```

there was a possibility to alias this somehow...

```
type SpecDef = ???
trait Foo[SpecDef ??? A]
trait Bar[SpecDef ??? A]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is in the object `scala.Specializable`:

```
import scala.{specialized => spec, Specializable => Spec}
final val MySpec = new Spec.Group((Int, Float, Double, Long, Char, Boolean))

trait Foo[@spec(MySpec) A]
trait Bar[@spec(MySpec) A]
```